# Who in Star Trek has instructed subordinates "That's an order!" the most times?

Tags: star-trek

This phrase is used by a superior officer to remind a subordinate that a decision is final and orders are to be carried out, under penalty of insubordination charges.

A quick [search](https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&authuser=0#authuser=0&q=site:chakoteya.net+%22that%27s+an+order%22) shows us the phrase is common in all Star Trek series (plus Doctor Who, Andromeda, and others).   (Warning: [TV Tropes link](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThatsAnOrder))

## Which Star Trek character has used it the most times?

Very short close equivalents are acceptable too.  If it's not obviously a variant,  please seek clarification.

Comment: As per your wish, I didn't flag the comment thread for clean-up.  Someone else must have (or a moderator noticed it was getting long).

Comment: @Praxis.   I'm sure.   I don't favour this kind of cleanup because it means we have to have the same discussion every time.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to count past tense examples like this "Mister Spock, I gave you an order to stay in the Sickbay" in [Operation: Annihilate!](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/29.htm), or "I gave you an order, Mister Farrell" from [The Enemy Within](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/5.htm)?

Comment: @Hypnosifl:   Maybe.  The difference is whether it's used to escalate a command or to point out insubordination post facto.

Comment: The exchange in The Enemy Within was: "KIRK: Prepare to leave orbit, Mister Farrell. Well? FARRELL: Captain! KIRK: I gave you an order, Mister Farrell. FARRELL: But what about- KIRK: They can't be saved. Prepare to leave orbit. FARRELL: Yes, sir. " That would seem to be escalating his command--would you agree? A complication is that this was an episode where Kirk had been split into two by a transporter accident, and this was his more impulsive, violent, and "id"-like side--would you discount it for that reason?

Comment: @Hypnosifl, I would agree that this is close enough to "That's an order".   Does that count as Kirk?   I guess so.

Answer (score 9):

## Kirk: 17 times

Kirk asserts "That's an order" in the following *TOS* and *TAS* episodes:

- "Where No Man Has Gone Before"
- "The Deadly Years"
- "The Return of the Archons"
- "Mirror, Mirror"
- "Shore Leave"
- "This Side of Paradise"
- "The Infinite Vulcan"
- "Who Mourns for Adonais?" **(twice)**
- "The Immunity Syndrome"
- "The Devil in the Dark"
- "The Cloud Miners"
- "The Trouble with Tribbles"
- "The Lights of Zetar"

He also says it once in *Star Trek* (2009) and twice in *Into Darkness*, including:

> And enough with the metaphors, all right? **That's an order.**

Comment: I'd insert the actual instances, but they all consist of *That's an order*, and so I'm not sure how illuminating it would be.

Comment: I'll take your word for it: +1

Comment: @N_Soong : No worries, but Kirk says it in *Into Darkness*, so that takes Kirk up a notch. ;-)

Comment: Well 17 certainly beats 15 then; well done!

Comment: @N_Soong : You forced me to overcome my natural aversion to the reboot films. ;-)

Comment: As Kristine James mentioned in her answer, Kirk doesn't say "that's an order" in "The Trouble With Tribbles" (though Scotty does).

Comment: @Hypnosifl : My mistake.  I'll fix it later.  :-)

Comment: Kirk also says "*No, I do not understand. Explain. **Consider that an order**."* in Amok Time

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT**: At the time this was posted, @Praxis' answer above was "Kirk: 14", so at that point 15 was the highest number.

## Archer: 15

- 'Terra Prime'

  > ARCHER: Give me the phase pistol. That's an order.
- 'Twilight':

  > ARCHER: At this point, it won't make much of a difference. You two get to a shuttlepod. They're only after humans. If this doesn't work out you'll still have a chance. That's an order.
- 'Demons':

  > ARCHER: Clap louder. That's an order.
- 'Strange new worlds':

  > ARCHER: Put your weapon down, Trip. That's an order.
- 'Minefield':

  > ARCHER: We're wasting time. Help me figure out a way to get you off of here. That's an order. 
  >   (and later)
  >   ARCHER: I'm not going to argue with you, Malcolm. It was twenty. That's an order.
- 'Ceasefire':

  > ARCHER: That's an order. No offence, but my ears are less likely to draw fire than yours.
- 'Harbinger':

  > ARCHER: Don't try to tell me who started it! I don't know what the problem is between you two, and to tell you the truth I don't care, but I want it settled right now. Settle it! That's an order!
- 'Silent Enemy'

  > ARCHER: Get some help if you need it, but make this a top priority. That's an order.
- 'Desert Crossing'

  > ARCHER: You drink it. That's an order.

  (and later)

  > ARCHER: Name them. That's an order.
- 'Shadows of P'Jem':

  > ARCHER: I didn't ask if you were hungry. You need to keep up your strength, so eat. That's an order.
- 'Aquisition'

  > ARCHER: Not another word, Commander. That's an order.

  (and later)

  > ARCHER: Five bars of gold? Open these things, Sub-Commander. That's an order.
- 'Unexpected':

  > ARCHER: Take a nap, Trip. That's an order.
- 'The Forgotten':

  > ARCHER [OC]: That's an order.

Followed by...

## Janeway: 14

- 'Scorpion':

  > JANEWAY: Fight it, Harry. That's an order.
- 'Dark Frontier'

  > JANEWAY: Keep moving. That's an order.

  (and later in that episode)

  > JANEWAY: No, now. That's an order.
- 'The Voyager Conspiracy':

  > JANEWAY: Turn this ship around. That's an order.
- 'Unimatrix Zero':

  > JANEWAY: Without the Doctor's help, that could kill you. Stay focused. Stay Tuvok. That's an order.

  (and later in that episode)

  > JANEWAY: You're Commander Tuvok, Tactical Officer of the starship Voyager. I'm your captain. Step aside, that's an order.
- 'Paturation':

  > JANEWAY: That's an order.
- 'Coda':

  > JANEWAY: Turn it off. That's an order, Doctor!
- 'Timeless':

  > JANEWAY: Cancel it, that's an order.
- 'Mortal Coil':

  > JANEWAY: No. You are taking some time off, and that's an order.
- 'Waking Moments':

  > JANEWAY: That's an order!
- 'Vis a Vis':

  > JANEWAY: That's an order.
- 'Time and Again':

  > JANEWAY: You're not to warn these people. That's an order.
- 'Drone':

  > JANEWAY: What I'm proposing is the only defence we have against that possibility, short of murder, and that's an order I'd prefer not to give. As I recall, Seven, there were a few crew members who had similar doubts about you.

And just out of interest's sake:

## Chakotay: 8

- 'Year of Hell':

  > CHAKOTAY: You're not doing anything against Annorax. That's an order.
- 'Unimatrix Zero':

  > CHAKOTAY: Open it, that's an order. Not only late but improperly dressed. That belongs on your collar, Mister Paris.
- 'Night':

  > CHAKOTAY: Seven, I want good news. That's an order.
- 'Parallax':

  > CHAKOTAY: Look, Lieutenant, I don't have to explain myself to you. I'll deal with B'Elanna personally, and then I'll inform the Captain. You're to drop this matter. That's an order.
- 'Pathfinder'

  > CHAKOTAY: Sit down, Lieutenant, and give us mortals a chance to get even. That's an order.
- 'Mortal Coil':

  > CHAKOTAY: Good. I get off duty at fourteen hundred hours. Meet me in my quarters and we'll begin. That's an order.
- 'Tsunkatse':

  > CHAKOTAY: It's your shore leave. But try to enjoy yourselves. That's an order.
- 'Memorial'

  > CHAKOTAY: Neelix, this is Commander Chakotay. Let Naomi go. No one's going to hurt her. That's an order.

## Picard: 8

- *Star Trek Insurrection*:

  > PICARD: Return to your quarters. ...**That's an order**.
- 'Encounter at Farpoint':

  > PICARD: Everyone at ease. **That's an order.** Q, my people are in trouble. Let me help them, please. I'll do whatever you say.
- *Star Trek Nemesis*:

  > PICARD: That's an order, Commander.
- 'QPid':

  > PICARD: Quick, into the forest. Mister Worf. **That's an order**.
- 'Disaster':

  > PICARD: My ankle is broken. I will just slow you down when you need to move quickly. Now, you are the leader. And that's an order.
- 'The Schizoid Man':

  > PICARD: Do it. That's an order.
- 'The Arsenal of Freedom'

  > PICARD: Come on, stay with me. Come on now, stay awake. That's an order.
- *Star Trek Generations* (courtesy @Kristine James):

  > PICARD: You will not be deactivated! You're an officer on board this ship and I require you to perform your duty. That is an order, Commander!

Answer (score 4):

I went through and found the quotes from the episodes/movies listed for Kirk:

Where No Man Has Gone Before:

KIRK: If you have not received a signal from me within twelve hours, you'll proceed at maximum warp to the nearest Earth base with my recommendation that this entire planet be subjected to a lethal concentration of neutron radiation. No protest on this, Mark. That's an order. -

Shore Leave:

KIRK: That's an order, Mister Spock.

The Deadly Years:

KIRK: That's an order, Lieutenant. Code two.

The Return of The Archons:

KIRK: That's an order. Watch him. Captain out.

Mirror Mirror:

KIRK: That's an order, Scotty. -

This Side of Paradise:

KIRK: Spock, I don't know what you think you're doing, but this is an order. Report back to me at the settlement in ten minutes. We're evacuating all colonists to Starbase Twenty Seven.

Who Mourns For Adonais?:

KIRK: And one more thing. I want no more unauthorised action against Apollo or whatever he is. That's an order!- ( and later)

KIRK: Fire those phasers! That's an order, Mister Spock! -

The Immunity Syndrome:

KIRK: No, no, no. That's an order.

The Devil in the Dark :

KIRK: You're a healer. There's a patient. That's an order. Mister Spock. Tell it we're trying to help. The mechanism.

The Cloud Minders:

KIRK: Officially, yes. But this mission is strictly unofficial. Nobody's to have any part in it, any responsibility for it, but myself. That's an order, Spock. You have the conn. Stand by till I contact you.

The Lights of Zetar:

KIRK: Get to Sickbay, Lieutenant. That's an order.

TAS The Infinite Vulcan:

KIRK: Out of my way, mister. That's an order.

ST2009:

KIRK: (to comm) Whatever happens, Mister Sulu, if you think you have the tactical advantage, you fire on that ship, even if we're still onboard. That's an order.

ST: Into Darkness:

Sign for the torpedoes, that's an order.

And enough with the metaphors, all right? That's an order.

My friend and I couldn't find where Kirk said it in The Trouble with Tribbles, so if someone could point it out for me, it would be appreciated.

Also Archer said it 16 times not 15.

'Terra Prime'

1. ARCHER: Give me the phase pistol. That's an order.

'Twilight':

2. ARCHER: At this point, it won't make much of a difference. You two get to a shuttlepod. They're only after humans. If this doesn't work out you'll still have a chance. That's an order.

'Demons':

3. ARCHER: Clap louder. That's an order.

'Strange new worlds':

4. ARCHER: Put your weapon down, Trip. That's an order.

'Minefield':

5. ARCHER: We're wasting time. Help me figure out a way to get you off of here. That's an order. (and later)
6. ARCHER: I'm not going to argue with you, Malcolm. It was twenty. That's an order.

'Ceasefire':

7. ARCHER: That's an order. No offence, but my ears are less likely to draw fire than yours.

'Harbinger':

8. ARCHER: Don't try to tell me who started it! I don't know what the problem is between you two, and to tell you the truth I don't care, but I want it settled right now. Settle it! That's an order!

'Silent Enemy'

9. ARCHER: Get some help if you need it, but make this a top priority. That's an order.

'Desert Crossing'

10 .ARCHER: You drink it. That's an order.

(and later)

11. ARCHER: Name them. That's an order.

'Shadows of P'Jem':

12 .ARCHER: I didn't ask if you were hungry. You need to keep up your strength, so eat. That's an order.

'Aquisition'

13. ARCHER: Not another word, Commander. That's an order.

(and later)

14. ARCHER: Five bars of gold? Open these things, Sub-Commander. That's an order.

'Unexpected':

15. ARCHER: Take a nap, Trip. That's an order.

'The Forgotten':

16. ARCHER [OC]: That's an order.

So unless someone can find Kirk's That's an order in The Trouble with Tribbles, Kirk and Archer are even with 16 each.

Comment: Nice work--it was Scotty who said "That's an order" in "The Trouble With Tribbles", not Kirk, as one can see from the transcript [here](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/42.htm) (do control-F, or command-F on a Mac, to search for a specific phrase).

Comment: Nice answer, but it is not necessary to put them all in.

Answer (score -1):

Picard also said That is an order in Generations.

PICARD: You will not be deactivated! You're an officer on board this ship and I require you to perform your duty. That is an order, Commander!

So that's 8 for Picard.

Comment: Welcome to SFFSE!  Thanks for this, I'll add it into my answer, but just for future reference, this is better suited as a comment than a full answer in it's own right!

Comment: It wouldn't let me comment on your post bc I don't have enough reputation points.

Comment: 1 for Mr. Scott in "The Trouble with Tribbles", Chekov is about to start a fight with the Klingons when Scotty says "Don't do it Mister - and that's an order".